# Apache Spark´s behavior with Regular Files

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I have a spark application which reads data from a local file.

```
JavaRDD<String> file = context.textFile(input);
```

Since it is not a distributed file, I need a copy of the input file on every node at the same path.
Does this mean that every node will process the entire file? 
If yes, is there a way to keep the file non-distributed and make the nodes process different parts of the file without having a copy on every node?
Thank you!

Comment: You could try to load your input file just once in a network drive, making it visible for all your nodes... have you already tried?

Comment: @Panto No, I haven´t tried that yet..I was thinking if I already loaded the file in an JavaRDD, I could manipulate this JavaRDD, to be partitioned and distributed to the nodes. Is that possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that file would fit in memory of the driver, it is possible to load it using native code and then convert it to an RDD with `context.parallelize(data)` to distribute it in the cluster for further parallel processing.

In scala, one could do something like this:

```
val lines = Source.fromFile("/path/to/local/file").getLines()
val rdd = sparkContext.parallelize(lines.toSeq, numOfPartitions)
```